# Can't install buildozer

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I was trying to install a tool called [Buildozer](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that is used to compile python kivy programs into APKs.

I used

```
pip3 install --user --upgrade buildozer
```

as the installation guide said but that error occurred:

```
C:\Python3\Scripts>pip install buildozer
Collecting buildozer
  Using cached buildozer-1.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (84 kB)
Collecting sh
  Using cached sh-1.14.3.tar.gz (62 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Mohamed\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pt7naaa7\sh_21f177c5355f4c0ab5cf85a2821a9137\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
          import sh
        File "C:\Users\Mohamed\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pt7naaa7\sh_21f177c5355f4c0ab5cf85a2821a9137\sh.py", line 37, in <module>
          import fcntl
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried to install another version of python but it didn't work.

If someone can help me I will be grateful.

Comment: Install it into a Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) instance. AFAIK buildozer doesn't run on Windows directly

Answer (score 0):

Buildozer can't be used directly under Windows. It can be used on Windows running Ubuntu Linux via WSL. The official installation instruction can be found here:

https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

It recommends installing Java 17 but I personally had an [issue](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/1504) with JDK 17 thus I recommend to install JDK 11 instead.

1. Install Ubuntu 22.04.xx LTS from Microsoft Store

   https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9PN20MSR04DW
2. Run installed Ubuntu (terminal window) from Windows Start Menu or using PyCharm Terminal:

   [image]
3. Install Buildozer on Ubuntu by running following commands:

   ```
    sudo apt update

    sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-11-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev libssl-dev

    pip3 install --user --upgrade Cython==0.29.19 virtualenv

    echo "export PATH=\$PATH:~/.local/bin/" >> ~/.bashrc

    pip3 install --user --upgrade buildozer
   ```
4. Now make sure your current Ubuntu directory is set to your Python project's directory. If for example your project is stored within: `C:\Kivy\Projects\MyHelloWorld`, then change your Ubuntu current directory to `/mnt/c/Kivy/Projects/MyHelloWorld`:

   ```
   cd /mnt/c/Kivy/Projects/MyHelloWorld
   ```

   Note: using PyCharm terminal it will always set current directory to your project's folder
5. Make sure that your Windows user have Full Control access right to your project's folder under Windows
6. Generate initial `buildozer.spec` for your project under Ubuntu terminal:

   ```
    buildozer init
   ```
7. Change buildozer.spec lines:

   ```
    # android.accept_sdk_license = False
   ```

   to

   ```
    android.accept_sdk_license = True
   ```

   and

   ```
    #android.api = 27
   ```

   to

   ```
    android.api = 33
   ```
8. You can build your project using for example:

   ```
   buildozer -v android debug
   ```

First build attempt will take more than half an hour, because Buildozer will collect required stuff over internet into `.buildozer` folder of your Python project. Next build attempts will be more quicker.